# VB.Net Exception Unhandled: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, exception, filesystems

I'm trying to save a plot I write on Vb.Net 6.0 (Visual Studio 2022) to a .png file.

`bmp.Save("C:\graph.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`

However, in the above code segment, I get the following exception unhandled message:

*VB.Net Exception Unhandled:*

*System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+*

This is the rest of the script to which the code segment belongs to

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Drawing.Bitmap
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging



Public Class Form1
    Dim m, i As Integer
    Dim h, Pi, Pi2, u, v, x, y As Single
    Dim left As Integer = Me.left

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Dim top As Integer = Me.top
    Dim centerX As Integer = Me.left + (Me.Width / 2)
    Dim centerY As Integer = Me.top + (Me.Height / 2)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Dim path As String = "C:\graph.png"
    Dim perm As FileIOPermission = New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, path)



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        m = 1000
        h = 1 / 100
        Pi = 3.14
        Pi2 = 3.14 * 2
        x = 150
        y = 150

        For i = 1 To m
            u = x * Cos(h * Pi2) + y * Sin(h * Pi2)
            v = y * Cos(h * Pi2) - x * Sin(h * Pi2)
            x = u
            y = v
            g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)), x, y, 1, 1)
        Next i
        Try
            perm.Demand()
            ' The application has permission to write to the file
            bmp.Save("C:\graph.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Catch ex As SecurityException
            ' The application does not have permission to write to the file
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `"C:\graph.png"` with, e.g., `"C:\SomeFolderWhereI HaveWriteAccessForSure\graph.png"`? -- BTW, did you check what `CodeAccessPermission.Demand()` is actually for?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be saving a file to the root of the system drive. Windows protects you from doing such foolish things. If you want to save an image then it should probably be to the user's Pictures folder or the program's AppData folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your app with administrator privileges?

Starting with Windows 10, Windows doesn't want you to save files to the root of your C drive. So you should choose a different directory to save the file.